# Derived columns in Microsoft Excel

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to programmatically populate an excel sheet through Java, where basically, I want a cell of column C to be a sum of the corresponding cells in column A and column B

```
i.e.  Cn = An + Bn (n is the row number).
```

I can of course apply the formula to one row and then drag it all the way below to the last column. However, I was looking for a way in which this can be done without using an kind of manual intervention requiring someone to copy paste formulae across the entire column.

Comment: Please be more specific: `this can be done without using an kind of post-processing` - still unclear what solution is NOT that kind.

Comment: Made the required changes.